# How to infer params type for rxjs map operator in TS?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I create a custom function as below, as a helper function for `rxjs` map operator

```
function customMap(mapping: (item: TryToInfer) => any): OperatorFunction<KnownType, any> {
  // do something ...
  return map((res) => ({}))
}
```

how can I inter the function `mapping` param `TrytoInfer` ?

`TrytoInfer` is dynamic.

so I can use `customMap` easily, because I don't need to write the `item` type

---

usually, using rxjs, operator can infer callback param type.

```
of(1,2,3,4).pipe(
  // src type can be inferred as number
  map((src) => ({}))
)
```

what I want is the same thing, I want my callback param type can be inferred automatically.

Comment: More detail would be helpful. For example, you ask about inferring the argument type in `mapping`, but you don't show how `mapping` is used in `customMap`. Try to make the code snippet a [mre].

Comment: Without really understanding your requireements ... could you use generics? `customMap<T>()`